# Optimizing Mac mini power consumption with 24/7 uptime

Tags: power, power-management

We have a new outdoor cat, and my wife put an AirTag on her. I set up a bash script on my Mac Studio to read the Find My json every minute and append new info into a csv. So long as the Find My app is open and the computer is not sleeping, this gives us the last known AirTag location every minute.

But I don’t want to prevent my Mac Studio from sleeping. I also have an M1 Mac mini, so I’m thinking of using that as a headless server, but I want to keep power consumption very very low. What I have so far:

- Clean install of macOS. Set for manual updates.
- Log it into iCloud, but turn off all services except Find My
- Turn off Spotlight indexing.
- Only Find My app and bash script running (bash script uses very
  little power)
- Turn down polling to every 3 or 5 min instead of 1.

Anything else I should be doing to keep this thing just sipping power?

Comment: I think you should get a kill-a-watt device (or similar) to measure the actual power consumption before snd after these tweaks.  I would posit the delta between the two states will be negligible to non-existsnt.

Comment: Cats are not outdoor animals.

Comment: @Allan already have one at the ready. I was just hoping to get this thing as close to zero as possible so I can feel less guilty about running a single-purpose server like that.

Comment: @MarcWilson Humans feel the need to comment on things they know nothing about.

Comment: @MarcWilson tell that to the farm cats and they are good ratters.

Comment: An M1 Mini uses between 7W (idling) and 39W (max load). You'll be (un)lucky if you use more than 10W average. The Studio uses between 13W idle and up to 215W maximum load. I suspect that running the Mini would be cheaper than the Studio not sleeping. Either way, it's probably pennies.

Comment: @MarcWilson - "Cats are not outdoor animals." may be the most bizarre statement I've heard in a long time.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks. So 7W is minimum? At 10W about 88 kWh a year. I guess I can live with that